# How to add a Signature stamp to Okular

Tags: pdf, okular

I'd like to have my own signature as a stamp for Okular.

In folder `/usr/share/okular` there is a config file drawingtools.xml and in folder `/usr/share/okular/pic` the is a stamps.svg containing some pictures with stamps. But it seems not to be made for adding more pictures.

Is there a easy, lean and clean way to insert my own graphic?

**Edit**:

I found this:

source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Okular/

> Eigene Stempel definieren
>
> Okular bietet die Möglichkeit, eigene Stempel zu definieren, die dann
>   als Markierung ins Dokumment einfügt werden können.
>
> Dazu muss man zuerst den gewünschten Text oder das gewünschte Bild als
>   .png oder .svg Datei im Homeverzeichnis unter `.kde/share/icons`
>   speichern, Dateinamen und Dateiendung dürfen ausschließlich aus
>   Kleinbuchstaben bestehen. Sollte das Verzeichnis nicht existieren,
>   dann muss man es vorher noch anlegen.
>
> Danach wählt man das Menü "Einstellungen -> Anmerkungen einrichten"
>   und dort "Hinzufügen -> Typ:Stempel". Im oberen Feld kann man einen
>   eigenen, frei wählbaren Namen eingeben, im unteren Feld unter "Stempel
>   Symbol" gibt man den Namen der zuvor gespeichert Stempeldatei ein.
>   Findet Okular diese, wird eine Vorschau rechts neben der Eingabe
>   angezeigt. Mit einem Klick auf "Ok" ist der eigene Stempel angelegt
>   und einsatzbereit. Im Menü mit den Werkzeugen wird der Stempel jetzt
>   angezeigt.

And the Google Translate version:

> Define your own stamps
>
> Okular offers the possibility to define own stamps, which can then be inserted as a marking in the document.
>
> To do this you must first save the desired text or image as .png or .svg file in the home directory under .kde / share / icons,
>   filenames and file extensions may only consist of lowercase letters.
>   If the directory does not exist, you have to create it first.
>
> Then select the menu "Settings -> Set up notes" and there "Add -> Type: Stamp". In the upper field you can enter your own, freely
>   selectable name, in the lower field under "Stamp Symbol" you enter the
>   name of the previously saved stamp file. If eyepiece finds this, a
>   preview will be displayed to the right of the input. With a click on
>   "Ok" your own stamp is created and ready for use. In the menu with the
>   tools, the stamp is now displayed.

But putting a sig.png in `.kde/share/icons` didn't helped. It's not shown if entering the name as Stamp-Symbol.

I use Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: The current answers should be updated for Okular Version 20.12.3. There is a more up-to-date guide at https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/s2aqn0/tip_add_your_signature_with_okular_to_a_pdf_sign/ but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With more recent versions of Okular, there seem to be an easier solution for this task.
I am using Okular 23.04 and this works for me:

Go to `Settings` -> `Configure Okular...` -> `Annotations` -> `Add` -> Select Type: `Stamp` -> Choose symbol file from your file system using the file picker button.

[image: Screenshot (can't post images yet...)]

You can use your new Stamp by clicking on this button in the top-right toolbar corner and selecting it from the drop-down menu.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Works for me on Okular 21.12.3 (Kubuntu 22.04). Pay attention to the second image to retrieve your personalized stamp (it does not appear in the stamps section)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This works well for me but the resulting stamp has way less resolution than the PNG I used. Is there any way to fix this? Also: is it possible to lock the aspect ratio when drawing the stamp area?

Answer (score 14):

First, please place your image in *~/.kde/share/icons*, creating the *icons* folder if need be.  (To be on the safe side, please use lowercase for the image name and avoid spaces).

[image: Adding your own stamp in Okular]

Then, as shown in the image above, you need to type or paste in the **entire** path and filename like

*/home/rundekugel/.kde/share/icons/mysignature.png*

assuming that your username is *rundekugel* and that *mysignature.png* is the relevant image.

This is a recognized usability issue in Okular version 1.3.3 that ships in Bionic and is being addressed in [Make custom stamp image support more discoverable](https://phabricator.kde.org/T8074).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. Two notes: 1) The picture file can be anywhere, no need to put it in `~/.kde/share/icons/`. 2) If the picture file is a `jpeg` or a `jpg` file, you *should not specify the extension in the path* (yes, that's weird). That is, use `/home/rundekugel/.kde/share/icons/mysignature` instead of `/home/rundekugel/.kde/share/icons/mysignature.jpg`.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, and this didn't work for me. I created the icons folder within .kde/share and copied the filename using <copy> from Dolphin-file-explorer both with a prepending "file:///" (which firefox finds and displays image of) and also with just the /home/me/.kde/share/icons/my.png  ALSO, the png must be "flattened" in GIMP or other photoediting software (it may not have an alpha channel or transparency to it).

Comment: @user12711 please post your own answer and ping me when you do if you feel like. I think your answer will be very helpful. (I'm not going to be able to edit my answer to include your findings because I don't have time.) Thanks!

Comment: I get this warning when trying to create a stamp: "Warning: experimental feature.
Stamps inserted in PDF documents are not visible in PDF readers other than Okular."

Comment: @GTF, sadly, quite a few features, not just stamps, **don't** appear to work in other PDF readers.

Comment: @GTF Also, if you print a PDF with a stamp to another PDF, the stamp is NOT included (but text annotations are).

Comment: However, there is [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225245/365707) on another SE site which solved my problem.

Comment: @John I also use XournalPP for this now, but it's a bit of an ugly workflow compared to e.g. Preview on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

the only way that adding my signature works is by putting the full path `/home/me/.kde/share/icons/stamp.png`, and not `~/.kde/share/icons/stamp.png`

I tried putting the link to my images folder and it didn't work either.

Using Linux Min 19.2

Comment: This is exactly what @DK Bose answer says. "Paste in the __entire__ path...".

Answer (score 0):

I can't add anything because when I click or right-click on the place for signature, nothing happens. I toggled the "Show forms" button, I tried to relaunch okular, it's as if this field wasn't editable at all. The text fields function fine. Maybe the pdf form I have to fill in is bad. It's something I downloaded from an administration web site, I have to fill it in and send it back.

If the same thing happens to you, you can always do it manually. Zoom out until you see the whole page and take a screenshot. Then open the png file with your favorite paint program and add the signature. Don't forget to remove all the surrounding stuff, only keep the picture of the page.

The problem is, if you have a document with several pages, you have to screenshot them all and then re-assemble. You can use LibreOffice to do that. Open a blank writer page, set the margins to zero width and import all your pages in order. Then use "export as/pdf".

This is the last resort solution, the methods explained above are faster.