# How do I sign PDF documents like I can in Preview on my mac

Tags: pdf, desktop-apps

I'm not asking about digitally (cryptographically) signing a document, but rather about an alternative to Preview.app on MacOS (which, to be honest, is a really good tool) which will allow me to add a signature to a PDF document (I have to sign things all the time). At the moment I'm doing this with GIMP which is really tedious.

Comment: inkscape and libreoffice can handle pdfs too

Comment: have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132658/how-to-add-a-signature-stamp-to-okular

Comment: @db429 -- libreoffice ruined the formatting of the document I was trying to sign when I opened it. I also just want something as simple as Preview.

Comment: @db429 I am trying Okular, but it has the following warning: "Warning: experimental feature.
Stamps inserted in PDF documents are not visible in PDF readers other than Okular."

Comment: Can confirm that Okular doesn't work -- if I open the PDF in another document the signature is gone.

Comment: as a workaround you might use the print-to-file functionality of the regular print interface